# How to limit a join to one result per record, in order for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I currently have two tables, one for `pages` (objects) and one for `images` (media).

I want to get a list of all the pages in the system, and join a single image record onto each page record. It's very close to working now, but it is returning all of the records, when I just want to get one back.

I've tried a few sub queries + Distinct, but not quite got it working yet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I've tried group by, but it doesn't work after doing the sort and therefore brings back the wrong image.

```
SELECT title, 
   url, 
   media_file, 
   media_order
FROM ndxz_objects 
   LEFT JOIN ndxz_media ON ndxz_objects.id = ndxz_media.media_ref_id
WHERE `status` = 1
   AND `section_id` = 2
GROUP BY title, url, media_file, media_order
ORDER BY ndxz_objects.ord, ndxz_media.media_order
```

Comment: What's the table structure of `ndxz_media`?  Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ndxz_media;`? May be able to use an incremental id inside there if there is one.

Comment: Yes, there is an incrementing int inside both tables. The structure of the tables isn't too bad, compared to some of the questions I have seen like that. I also have control to make changes if needed, but it seems to be this should be a fairly standard type of lookup?

Comment: Just to be clear, each page can have many images associated with it, I just want 1 to come back, which is defined by media_order on the media table.

Comment: Is it the highest or lowest `media_order` you want? My example works with the auto_increment id, but I can modify it.

Comment: It's the lowest media_order I'm looking for, thanks. So what it seems you are doing is the grouping by the id inside the media table, and there fore the join only matches on the singular records from the sub query?

Comment: See the subquery at the bottom of my answer.  The join should only match singular records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find that query worked, this is what I used in the end.

```
SELECT title, url, media_file
FROM ".PX."objects
LEFT JOIN
    (
SELECT m1.media_id, m1.media_ref_id, m1.media_file, m1.media_order
    FROM ".PX."media AS m1
    LEFT JOIN ".PX."media AS m2 ON m1.media_ref_id = m2.media_ref_id AND m1.media_order    > m2.media_order
    WHERE m2.media_ref_id IS NULL        
    )
maxmedia ON ndxz_objects.id = maxmedia.media_ref_id
WHERE `status` = 1
AND `section_id` = 2
ORDER BY `ord`
```

I found this from the within group aggrigates section here [which seems like a good group of sql examples](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#101)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` inside `ndxz_media` called `id` (for example), you can get the `MAX(id)` or `MIN(id)` in a subquery, and join against it.

I think this works because MySQL allows columns not specified in the `GROUP BY` to be included along with the aggregate. Here, that's `media_file` and `media_order` in the subquery.

```
SELECT title, 
   url, 
   media_file, 
   media_order
FROM ndxz_objects
  JOIN (
     SELECT media_ref_id, MIN(media_order), media_file
     FROM ndxz_media
     GROUP BY media_ref_id
  ) maxmedia ON ndxz_objects.id = maxmedia.media_ref_id
WHERE etc. etc. etc.
```

Assuming `media_order` as a high/low value instead of using the theoretical `id`, the inner subquery would look like the following.  Everything else outside the parens doesn't change.

```
SELECT
  media_ref_id,
  MIN(media_order) AS media_order,
  media_file
FROM ndxz_media
GROUP BY media_ref_id, media_file
```

Run the subquery alone first.  It should retrieve singular records.  Then when placed into the parens, the join should work properly.

Comment: Hey, maybe I got something wrong in your query, but the sub query only returned one record.